# Drupal 8 Custom CSS not updateing

Tags: css, drupal-8

I have a drupal 8 installation with adaptive theme installed.
I have used this to generate my own theme (peterstheme) 
This allows for custom css.

I have an issue in that I can now not update my custom css.
When in Drupal I go to 
Home -> Administration -> Appearance -> Appearance settings 
to the custom CSS tab I can see the contents of the custom-css.css file
Here it says 
Styles entered here are saved to themes/exceed/styles/css/generated/custom-css.css.
When I save any changes it does not save them and definitely not to that file.

When I go to the drupal/themes/exceed/styles/css/generated/custom-css.css
and edit it directly the changes do not reflect in the drupal custom css.

I have flushed all the caches in drupal, cleared browser caches etc.

I have Configuration -> Performance. Set page cache to no-caching.
I have made sure that the permissions on the custom-css.css have (User ,Group,World read and write) or (666)

I cannot find any other custom-css.css file. 
I must be missing something.
I do not want to rebuild a whole new theme how can I update this?

Thanks in advance.
Peter

Answer (score -1):

You need to add the css file path in **ThemeName.libraries.yml** file under css section.